# Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.dylib

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, minecraft, macos-catalina

I am trying to create a Minecraft mod using [this](https://gist.github.com/Earthcomputer/afe6f6da5eb8d93a2cb4aec453d6b912) tutorial, altering the version to work with `1.15.1`.

I moved a few files around to get it to work, but then this happened:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Everything's going to plan. No, really, that was supposed to happen.

Time: 12/04/20 1:44 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.dylib
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer$Default.<clinit>(Pointer.java:61)
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.func_211162_a(MainWindow.java:121)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GLX._initGlfw(GLX.java:69)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.initBackendSystem(RenderSystem.java:530)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:367)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:138)
    at inject.mcp.client.Start.main(Start.java:19)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer$Default.<clinit>(Pointer.java:61)
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.func_211162_a(MainWindow.java:121)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GLX._initGlfw(GLX.java:69)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.initBackendSystem(RenderSystem.java:530)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:367)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:138)
    at inject.mcp.client.Start.main(Start.java:19)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.15.1
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.15.1
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.15.2
    Java Version: 1.8.0_241, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 547425376 bytes (522 MB) / 862978048 bytes (823 MB) up to 1908932608 bytes (1820 MB)
    CPUs: 8
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    Launched Version: mcp
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.1 build 12
    Backend API: ~~ERROR~~ NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Very likely; Jar signature invalidated
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

It seems that it cannot locate the library "liblwjgl.dylib".

Upon checking for this library, I found a file that might match:
[liblwjgl.dylib.sha1 is located within the Project and external dependencies under lwjgl-3.2.1.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdHBI.png)

For some reason, however, that doesn't seem to work. I've not seen a file suffixed `.sha1` before, what is it's a function? It contains one line, a hash (I am assuming `sha1`).

I am using *macOS* **Catalina, Java 8** and **Gradle 4.8.1** with **Eclipse 4.15.0**.

Comment: .sha1 is the hash to check integrity of the file. The actual file needs to be there on the path, that should work. The error points to a library not there on the path.

Comment: @Ironluca Where can I download the actual file?

Comment: What I understand it is a java gaming library for graphics etc. I found this Googling, there is a download link (https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL_(Legacy))

Comment: You should make your mod in 1.15.2

Comment: I presume you wanna create a minecraft mod using MinecraftForge as mod loader. If that is the case I suggest you to read the official minecraft forge documentation on how to setup the development environment https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.15.x/gettingstarted/

Comment: Addressing what @Flood2d said, I am actually making a mod using MCP-Config files. As for why I am making it in 1.15.1, the latest mappings from Searge to MCP, to my best knowledge, are in 1.15.1.

Comment: Also, the link @Ironluca gave does not give the `liblwjgl.dylib` file.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand its a dylib file (dynamic library) that is somewhere in the game files or forge files, and files that are missing in game files can be easily fixed by **reinstalling the game**. And if that doesn't fix it try **reinstalling the  mod loader**.

Comment: Again, not using forge